# .NET Core Web UI that best supports vanilla javascript with DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I have created a very interactive svg element with hundreds of individual components and many types of user interactions, right click menus, etc with vanilla javascript because it was so much faster than any framework.

It works great, the only problem is I now need to inject this into a website build with individual user logins, a database, a nice dashboard of past projects, etc. I need to have a button associated with the svg "save" the status and write to the database. I want to use ASP.NET for its friendliness with Microsoft products like Excel (I need to read user Excel uploads and parse Excel files).

My question is which ASP.NET core UI choice is going to allow me to build this full stack easiest, quickest, while injecting this svg with all of it's vanilla javascript functions.

I've watched youtube tutorials and read a lot of the microsoft docs on ASP.NET core and the UI choices.  I don't think webassembly with Blazor would be the way to go because it's too reliant on C#, and may slow down my javascript calls if I have to go through the c# middleman.  I really don't want to have to learn react or angular and do the SPA from the ground up, but if its what will maintain my quick vanilla javascript I'll forge ahead.  I think MVC might be the quickest way to build a website up quickly, but I"m not sure it will support my vanilla js with dom manipulation of the svg.

Comment: when you say "support my vanilla js/svg" what did you need?  Model binding with asp.net-core back-end?  Seems like any should support it... nice part about the svg is it's essentially text, so seems like you can bind that as an object in your "view model".  (if needed... maybe include some code your post?...)

Comment: well what I mean is there is a lot of interactivity with the svg, like dragging, selecting, manipulating the svg with vanilla javascript functions attached to the svg elements, sometimes up to 1000 elements.  I built it initially with react,, and it was so slow it woulddn't work.  So i built it with vanilla javascript functions, it was like 10x faster.  I need to keep those vanilla javascript functions the svg events call.

Comment: you can keep those... it's all client-side... for any ajax calls you can do that, too.  You'll decide what you want to return to your JS callbacks.  You can return html, json, etc... depends on what you needed.